# Get error 500 when loop does 200+ iterations

Tags: php, performance, loops, runtime-error

PHP Version 5.5.9
Apache 2
100 iterations works flawlessly, but if I tried more (for example, 200), I got ERROR 500.
I check memory consumption, it doesn't look so bad, about 600KB . So, IDK why it crashes to error, when I increase my iterator.
I tried some tricks, but had no luck with them.
IDK why, but if the script crashed to 500 error, it doesn't show me even first echos... So, I cannot to debug it by myself

Following code:

```
<?
//load constantes
if (is_file('config.php')) {
        require_once('config.php');
}
//set charset
ini_set("default_charset",'windows-1251');//utf-8
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
set_time_limit(600);

//create 

$MyArrayOfAvailItems=array();

    for($i = 0; $i < 200; $i++) {



            $model_id   = 5000+$i;
            //echo $model_id;
            //echo '
            //      ';            
            array_push($MyArrayOfAvailItems, $model_id);    

    }   



echo $MyArrayOfAvailItems[0];
echo '
                    ';
echo sizeof($MyArrayOfAvailItems);
echo '
                    ';

$MyArrayOfFindedItems=array();
//$item_container = "bx_catalog_item_container";
$item_container = "Сожалеем";
/* Convert, target encoding, source encoding*/
$item_container = mb_convert_encoding($item_container, "windows-1251", "utf-8");

function populateArray2($model, $data) {
    global $model;
    global $data;
    global $item_container;
    global $recurse;
    global $MyArrayOfFindedItems;
    /*
    if ($recurse === 1) {
        echo $item_container;
        echo $data;
        echo 'hello world '.$model;
        echo '
            ';
    }
    */
    $pos = strpos($data, $item_container);
    //echo $pos;
    if ($pos !== false) {
        array_push($MyArrayOfFindedItems, $model);
        echo $model;
        echo ' 
                ';
        //$recurse = 1; 
        //populateArray2($model, $data, $recurse);
    } else {
        //echo 'not found';
    } 

}
foreach ($MyArrayOfAvailItems as $model) {
    //$item_id = 5121;
    //echo $model;
    //echo '
    //              ';
    $data = file_get_contents('https://ufopeople.ru/catalog/?q='.$model);
    //echo $data;
    //echo '
    //              ';
    $recurse = 0;   
    populateArray2($model, $data);

}



//echo $data;
echo '
    ';
echo memory_get_usage(true)."\n";
echo memory_get_peak_usage(true)."\n";
//echo sizeof($MyArrayOfFindedItems);
/*
foreach ($MyArrayOfFindedItems as $checkit) {
    echo '
                    ';
    echo $checkit;  
}
*/
```

In apache logs only
    `[core:notice] [pid 20070] AH00052: child pid 17126 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)`
with timings, which are not correlate to me getting Error 500

Comment: anything in the (error) logs?

Comment: Where I should check them? I use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/186276/where-are-all-the-major-log-files-located might be your answer in there and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxLogFiles

Comment: @Fred-ii- [core:notice] [pid 20070] AH00052: child pid 17126 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
only that I found in my logs. And time of the records doesn't correlate with me getting ERROR 500

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed settings in php.ini file, which located here 
 
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
`max_execution_time = 300` (from 30)
and executed command:
`sudo service apache2 restart`
now it works

P.S.: it seems my php command

```
set_time_limit(600);
```

doesn't work.